# Discord py JSON file adding extra brackets

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having an issue where my JSON file, after a while, adds another bracket at the end of the file, which makes the leaderbord command unable to read the file.

This is my code:

```
dict = Counter()

    @commands.command()
    async def cupcake(self, ctx):
        id = str(user.id)
        if id in dict:
            dict[user.id] += 1
        else: 
            dict[user.id] += 1
            with open('users.json', 'r+') as f:
                json.dump(dict, f)
```

Then, I run the leaderboard command.

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def top(self, ctx):
        with open('users.json', 'r') as fg:
            data = json.load(fg)

        top_cakes = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

        names = ''
        for postion, user in enumerate(top_cakes):
            names += f'<@!{user}> has {top_cakes[user]}\n'

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Cupcake top", color=0xF9CF7A)
        embed.add_field(name="Top bakers:", value=names, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the JSON file: (I've replaced the actual user IDs)

```
{"USERID": 3, "USERID": 2}
```

And this is what happens after a few times of gaining points:

```
{"USERID": 1} "USERID": 2}
```

I can't pinpoint when it happens, it seems completely random. After a few times of gaining points, it adds another bracket to the first name. I am not sure what to do or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens when you write something like `{"USERID": 3, "USERID": 2}` and then, later, a shorter output like `{"USERID": 1}`; your code doesn't truncate the file in any way, so it only overwrites the beginning and the remainder of the older, longer output stays there.

Possible solutions:

- Open the file in `'w'` mode, which truncates the file before you write to it.
- Explicitly truncate the file (using `.truncate()`) after you write to it.

In this case, opening the file in `'w'` mode is probably the better way.

Comment: That seems to have fixed that error, thank you, but now, every time the bot restarts, and someone gains a point, it resets the JSON file, and all other users are deleted.

Comment: That's good, now you have a reproducible error :-)

In this case, you need to load the file into memory when the bot (re)starts.